# accessing POST parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I add a new "product" using my scaffold create rails app, the following line properly adds a new product

```
@product = Product.new(params[:product])
```

When I try to add a new product using the following URL (trying to POST data up from a java program).

```
http://localhost:3000/products?serial=555&value=111
```

The product is not created, however I can access the "serial" and "value" values like this:

```
 @product = Product.new
 @product.serial=params[:serial]
 @product.value=params[:value]
 @product.save
```

To further confuse me, if I use the rails app to add a new product, the `params[:serial]` and `params[:value]` variables are empty.

Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Model.new method takes a hash.

`params[:product]` actually contains something like `{:serial => 555, :value => 111}`

The url you would want to use is:

```
http://localhost:3000/products?product[serial]=555&product[value]=111
```

(Make sure that you are indeed using POST)

If you want to keep your current url scheme you would have to use:

```
@product = Product.new({:serial => params[:serial], :value => params[:value]})
```

You can also determine exactly what is available inside of params by printing it out to console using:

```
p params
```

Good luck!