# How can I get post parameter in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to get post parameter `deal_id` in controller.

*My view -> show.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for([@deal, @contract], :url => pay_payments_path, html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :deal_id, value: @deal.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>

  <%= f.submit "Send", :class => "btn btn-danger" %>

<% end %>
```

*My controller -> payments_controller*

```
def pay
   @deal = Deal.find(params[:deal_id])
end
```

My code in controller dont works, I got this:

```
Couldn't find Acordo with 'id'=
```

I want to get the `@deal` according `deal_id` parameter sent via post.

*Routes*

```
resources :payments, only: [:index, :new, :create] do
  collection do
    post :pay      
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting an empty value for `params[:deal_id]` you are probably missing adding it to the allowed parameters which may not be part of the default fields for a `Payment` resource:

```
def params
  params.require(:payment).permit(:deal_id)
end
```

Make sure you have the field in the params method on your payments controller.

Comment: @S_A I just noticed that you have the pay route as a collection, I think that should be a member route, not a collection, since you want to do only one. Try changing it to a member route.

Answer (score -1):

I am not a Ruby expert but maybe this can help you. 
[Accessing POST parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708035/accessing-post-parameters)